# Is it possible to insert blocks into content using the paragraphs module?

Tags: 7, nodes, blocks

I have a node (basic page type) with a lot of text (several paragraphs `<p>` of text).

Within two `<p>` tags I have to insert a block (generated with views oder other modules like Nodeblock).

How can I insert the existing block directly between the text of my node? Is it possible to do this with the "[Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs)" module?

If not, why not?

If not, which other modules allow me inserting blocks directly into the node text?

Answer (score 2):

you can install the [Viewfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield) module, create a view, then create a Paragraph with a field of type Viewfield which allows you to insert the view as content of the field.